# How to get the text of an svg desc element with javascript

Tags: web-applications, svg

right now I have a group of svg elements (circle, rect, path, etc.).The actual document looks something like this.

```
<desc>Some Text</desc>
<rect id='a0' fill='green' ...>
```

So when you you strip the a from the id you would get the corresponding desc element. I do this with the following code:

```
var WW = document.getElementsByTagName('desc')
var ZZ = evt.target.id
ZZ = ZZ.split('a')
ZZ = ZZ[1]
alert(WW[ZZ].firstChild)
```

But the only thing the is returned in the alert right now is:

```
[object Text]
```

Anybody have any ideas or suggestions? Any help would be great.

Comment: Using `alert` for debugging is a painful way to live. Look into `console.log` at a minimum, and breakpoint-based debugging available in [Chrome](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/), [Safari](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/safari/developer-tools.html), Firefox (via [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)), [Opera](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/introduction-to-opera-dragonfly/), and even [IE8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628(v=vs.85).aspx)+. Your future self will thank you for streamlining your development process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try

```
alert(WW[ZZ].firstChild.data);
```

Comment: I've actually tried that however the only thing it returns is undefined, even though each of those description elements have  descriptions within them.

Comment: OK how about this alert(WW[ZZ].firstChild.data)

Comment: WW[ZZ].firstChild.data works great. Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the main question (*How to get the text of an SVG `desc` element with JavaScript*), this would nowadays work fine:

```
document.querySelector( 'desc' ).textContent
```